# Partition a list of sets by shared elements

Tags: sql, algorithm, set

Here's the jist of the problem: Given a list of sets, such as:

```
[ (1,2,3), (5,2,6), (7,8,9), (6,12,13), (21,8,34), (19,20) ]
```

Return a list of groups of the sets, such that sets that have a shared element are in the same group.

```
[ [ (1,2,3), (5,2,6), (6,12,13) ], [ (7,8,9), (21,8,34) ], [ (19,20) ] ]
```

Note the stickeyness - the set (6,12,13) doesn't have a shared element with (1,2,3), but they get put in the same group because of (5,2,6).

To complicate matters, I should mention that I don't really have these neat sets, but rather a DB table with several million rows that looks like:

```
element | set_id
----------------
1       | 1
2       | 1
3       | 1
5       | 2
2       | 2
6       | 2
```

and so on. So I would love a way to do it in SQL, but I would be happy with a general direction for the solution.

**EDIT**: Changed the table column names to (element, set_id) instead of (key, group_id),  to make the terms more consistent. Note that Kev's answer uses the old column names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is exactly the computation of the connected components of an hypergraph: the integers are the vertices, and the sets are the hyperedges. A usual way of computing the connected components is by flooding them one after the other:

- for all i = 1 to N, do:
- if i has been tagged by some j < i, then continue (I mean skip to the next i)
- else flood_from(i,i)

where flood_from(i,j) would be defined as

- for each set S containing i, if it is not already tagged by j then:
- tag S by j and for each element k of S, if k is not already tagged by j, then tag it by j, and call flood_from(k,j)

The tags of the sets then give you the connected components you are looking for.

---

In terms of databases, the algorithm can be expressed as follows: you add a TAG column to your database, and you compute the connected component of set i by doing

- S = select all rows where set_id == i
- set TAG to i for the rows in S
- S' = select all rows where TAG is not set and where element is in element(S)
- while S' is not empty, do
- ---- set TAG to i for the rows in S'
- ---- S'' = select all rows where TAG is not set and where element is in element(S')
- ---- S = S union S'
- ---- S' = S''
- return set_id(S)

---

Another (theoretical) way of presenting this algorithm would be to say that you are looking for the fixed points of a mapping:

- if A = {A<sub>1</sub>, ..., A<sub>n</sub>} is a set of sets, define union(A) = A<sub>1</sub> union ... union A<sub>n</sub>
- if K = {k<sub>1</sub>, ..., k<sub>p</sub>} is a set of integers, define incidences(K) = the set of sets which intersect K

Then if S is a set, the connected component of S is obtained by iterating (incidences)o(union) on S until a fixed point is reached:

1. K = S
2. K' = incidences(union(K)).
3. if K == K', then return K, else K = K' and go to 2.

Comment: Kudos for the effort! Can you take a look at my answer and tell me if it's wrong, basically the same as your solution, or just a different solution?

Comment: It seems to me that you would need some merging step for your solution to be complete: you may start different goup_ids for sets that should be in the same group, because you have not discovered that yet. If you have a duplicate and both sets are in different groups, merge the two groups.

Answer (score 1):

You could think of it as a graph problem where the set (1,2,3) is connected to the set (5,2,6) via the 2. And then use a standard algorithm to fine the connected sub-graphs.

Here's a quick python implementation:

```
nodes = [ [1,2,3], [2,4,5], [6,7,8], [10,11,12], [7,10,13], [12], [] ]
links = [ set() for x in nodes ]

#first find the links
for n in range(len(nodes)):
    for item in nodes[n]:
        for m in range(n+1, len(nodes)):
            if (item in nodes[m]):
                links[n].add(m)
                links[m].add(n)

sets = []
nodes_not_in_a_set = range(len(nodes))

while len(nodes_not_in_a_set) > 0:
    nodes_to_explore = [nodes_not_in_a_set.pop()]
    current_set = set()
    while len(nodes_to_explore) > 0:
        current_node = nodes_to_explore.pop()
        current_set.add(current_node)
        if current_node in nodes_not_in_a_set:
            nodes_not_in_a_set.remove(current_node)
        for l in links[current_node]:
            if l not in current_set and l not in nodes_to_explore:
                nodes_to_explore.append(l)
    if len(current_set) > 0:
        sets.append(current_set)

for s in sets:
    print [nodes[n] for n in s]
```

output:

```
[[]]
[[6, 7, 8], [10, 11, 12], [7, 10, 13], [12]]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: This is tough to do without lft,rgt strategy (unless you want loops galore for the tree traversal)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely pretty inefficient, but it should work, at least:  Start with a key, select all the groups containing that key, select all the keys of those groups, select all the groups containing those keys, etc., and as soon as a step adds no new keys or groups, you have a list of all the groups of one sub-graph.  Exclude those and repeat from the beginning until you have no data left.

In terms of SQL this would need a stored procedure, I think.  WITH RECURSIVE might help you somehow, but I don't have any experience with it yet, and I'm not sure it's available on your DB backend.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this some more, I came up with this:

1. Create a table called `groups` with columns `(group_id, set_id)`
2. Sort the `sets` table by `element`. Now it should be easy to find duplicate elements.
3. Iterate through the sets table, and when you find a duplicate element do:

   1. if one of the `set_id` fields exists in the `groups` table, add the other one with the same `group_id`.
   2. If neither `set_id` exists in the `groups` table, generate a new group ID, and add both `set_id`s to the `groups` table.

In the end I should have a `groups` table containing all the sets.

This is not pure SQL, but seems like O(nlogn), so I guess I can live with that.

[Matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178913/partition-a-list-of-sets-by-shared-elements#178940) seems more correct, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my case.